# angular embed SWF for IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flash

I am trying to embed a SWF using angular which I have working in a directive I wrote.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('flash-embed', []).directive('flashEmbed', [function()
{
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: ['',
     '<object data="{{ src }}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">',
        '<param name="movie" value="{{ src }}" />',
        '<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />',
        '<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />',
      '</object>'
    ].join(''),
    scope: {
      width:'@',
      height:'@',
      src: '@',
      path:'@',
      wmode:'@'
    },
    compile: function(elem, attrs, transcludeFn)
    {
      return function link (scope, element, attrs)
      {
        scope.$watch('path', function(path)
        {
          if (path)
          {
            if (!attrs.wmode) attrs.wmode = 'transparent';
            element.append('<param name="flashvars" value="path=' + attrs.path + '" />');
            element.append('<param name="wmode" value="' + attrs.wmode + '" />');
          }
        });
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

The directive above works great in modern browsers. I cannot seem to get this to work in IE8 though. The SWF doesn't load and I get a SUPER DESCRIPTIVE error in the console that says:

> [Object Error] description: "Invalid argument." message:     "Invalid
>   argument." name:        "Error" number:      -2147024809

I found this thread: ["Invalid argument" in IE 8 on jQuery.prepend() on flash objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9150938/invalid-argument-in-ie-8-on-jquery-prepend-on-flash-objects)

that talks about IE not liking you change the object tag after it has already been defined. I've been trying to fix this for half of my day. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If it is AngularJS 1.3 or later, the problem is likely the framework itself not supporting IE8 or earlier:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: I am aware of that part so I am using angular 1.2.9, thanks anyway. I should have specified that